# Xcode 4.2 creating navigation based application

Tags: xcode4.2, navigationcontroller

I just tried to create navigation based application via xcode 4.2 
  and all I found in the new window have nothing to do with navigation based application .. I found page based application which is the nearest thing to the navigation based application

but it created with the story board which I can't handle yet..

[image]

So is there a way to create the good old nav based app? and if not what the alternatives?

Comment: This helped me to set upo an navigation based app: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews

Answer (score 13):

For Navigation only application, you have to chose single view application first. This will give only a view based application without navigationcontroller.

All you have to do is select the viewcontroller and goto menu

```
Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller
```

This will give you a navigation based project to start work with.

as @Tommy Herbert said, you can choose master-detail application template where you can select more option like Core data. But this will name your first two VC as master-controller and detailcontroller which is not apt.

Comment: I tried this, but when I go to the embed in option when the xib is selected, the Navigation Controller option is greyed out. Is there any other way?

Comment: @MSgambel you need to select the view or viewcontroller from "View Controller scene"

Comment: To make this clearer, you have to include Storyboards in order to select "Embed In", as this is only enabled when you select the storyboard resource. My suggestion, below, is to keep a copy of Xcode 3 and create the project there, then open the project in Xcode 4.

Comment: @MSgambel How can you get Navigation Controller option in editor?Because I have same problem but could not understand properly.If i don't use story board in Single view then how could i get that option describe in Editor "-> Embed In -> Navigation Controller".

Answer (score 4):

Until you're comfortable with the new features in iOS 5 (Storyboards, Page View Controllers, etc.), your best bet is to keep a copy of Xcode 3 and create your project there, then open the project in Xcode 4.

You can still download the last version of Xcode 3 (3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3) from the developer page:

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios

The "About Xcode and iOS SDK" PDF on the install disk describes how to choose a custom install location to avoid overwriting your Xcode 4 install. Don't select the Unix tools option as that will overwrite that portion of your current Xcode 4 install.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm starting iOS development now, and it was *very* confusing, to see one thing in the videos, and when I went to the IDE it was totally different!

Comment: it's not about comfort sir it's about making a backward compatible app.. if i use story board it will never work for prior ios 5

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert Master detail app. This template provides a starting point for a master-detail application. It provides a user interface configured with a navigation controller to display a list of items and also a split view on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

When you press Next after selecting the project template, there's a few checkboxes at the bottom of the screen. One of those is "Use Storyboard". Untick that and you'll go back to the old way of designing interfaces.

Comment: yeah i say that in my question :) the thing is the checkbox of storyboard is not there in the page based app

Comment: You can select it on the Master-Detail app type (which in the description lists it as being navigation controller-based).

Answer (score 0):

As darvids0n says, you should start from the Master-Detail Application template rather than the Page-Based one. You're free to untick Use Storyboard while choosing options for the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Just create single view application, and in xib just drag'n'drop navigation controller from library to objects.

Answer (score 0):

for me , start build an empty project and then create a new MainWindow and then just drag the navigtioncontroller to the newwindow u create

Answer (score 0):

Open X-code Project -> create new project -> Click On Master Based Application
The window Is Open This Is The process For Creating Direct Navigation Based Applications