# Creating navigation based application with xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I am using xCode 4.3.1, and i need to create a navigation based application without the tabbars. How can i do this is xCode 4.3.1 ? (It is not as simple as xcode 4.2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.2 creating navigation based application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869594/xcode-4-2-creating-navigation-based-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing....

In ur Application Delegate us Following Code

```
YourClass *yourClassObj= [[YourClass alloc]init]; 
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourClassObj];      
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
[yourClassObj release];
```

YourClass will be the class which you want to be ur root view.

Let me know if it worked or if i can help u more
Cheers

Comment: Use Master Detail Template... the first template on the Template Screen